# Is VS 10.0 Runtime part of .Net framework 4?

Tags: .net, runtime, visual-c++

Are VC Runtimes part of .Net framework? also how can I get the VC 10.0 Runtime for download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does but it has a private copy, c:\windows\system32\msvcr100_clr0400.dll.  It is not suitable for use by a C or C++ program, it needs msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll.  Local deployment is now an option, you might want to take advantage of it.

The merge modules you'd need if you want to use an installer are already on your machine.  c:\program files\common files\merge modules.  Using a Setup project is probably the easiest way.  Add it with Project + Properties, Prerequisites, tick "Visual C++ 2010 Runtime libraries".  The download links Jon gave you are suitable if you want your customer to prep the machine.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this page (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84&displaylang=en) and [this one (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=BD512D9E-43C8-4655-81BF-9350143D5867) are what you're after:

> The Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installs runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries required to run applications developed with Visual C++ on a computer that does not have Visual C++ 2010 installed.

(I don't know if they're part of .NET 4 itself - are you writing a native app which *also* requires .NET 4 to be installed?)

Comment: thanks for the links.. I will accept @Hans answer for his explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for VS (Visual Studio) then:

Definitely not because .Net Framework 4 is just the collection of libraries and tools by which you can develop .NET 4 applications by any text editor, But VS 10.0 (VS 2010) is the IDE which provides you a complete environment and embedded useful utilities by which you can develop .Net applications with flexibility and ease.